# Combination Regmatches and Replacement for specific Character

Tags: r, replace, nlp, case, stringr

I've tried replace character which match with specific character or followed by "BT", but my codes failed. This is my codes:

```
df <- data.frame(
  exposure = c("123BT", "113BB", "116BB", "117BT")
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    exposure2 = case_when(exposure == regmatches("d+\\BT") ~ paste0("-", exposure),
                     TRUE ~ exposure)
  )
```

the error is:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `exposure2`.
i `exposure2 = case_when(...)`.
x argument "m" is missing, with no default
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Whereas my target is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  exposure = c("123BT", "113BB", "116BB", "117BT"),
exposure2 = c(-123, 113, 116, -117)
)
```

Comment: Most of the R regex functions have the input of vectors as the second or third argument. So you need to learn how to set up function to accept  vectors when they are not in the first position of the argument pairlist. It also appears that you didn't describe the problem in a manner that would explain your expected output. Your your explanation and the  code would not handle the case of terminating "BB".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use library `stringr`, you can extract your numbers with regex `(\\d)+`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    exposure2 = case_when(str_detect(exposure,"BT") ~ paste0("-", str_extract(exposure, "(\\d)+")),
                          TRUE ~ str_extract(exposure, "(\\d)+"))
  )
```

Output:

```
  exposure exposure2
1    123BT      -123
2    113BB       113
3    116BB       116
4    117BT      -117
```

If you still prefer use `regmatches` you can get same result with:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    exposure2 = case_when(exposure %in% regmatches(exposure, regexpr("\\d+BT", exposure)) ~ paste0("-", regmatches(exposure, regexpr("\\d+", exposure))),
                          TRUE ~ regmatches(exposure, regexpr("\\d+", exposure)))
  )
```

Comment: As described the alternative results should have been `TRUE ~ exposure`

Answer (score 0):

First, a concise solution that you can easily implement in your `dplyr::mutate`. Using `gsub` we remove characters and coerce the result `as.integer`. The result, we multiply by `1` or `-1` according to if the string contains `"BT"` or not; for this we use `grepl` (gives boolean) and add `1L` (coerces to integer) to get indices `1` or `2`.

```
c(1, -1)[grepl('BT', df$exposure) + 1L]*as.integer(gsub('\\D', '', df$exposure))
# [1] -123  113  116 -117
```

Above is the recommended solution. The solution you envision is much more complex since it processes the information not very efficient. I implement the logic in a small `f`unction<sup>1</sup> to demonstrate.

```
f <- \(x) {
  rm <- regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+BT", x))
  o <- gsub('\\D', '', x)
  o <- ifelse(x %in% rm, paste0('-', o), o)
  as.integer(o)
}

f(df$exposure)
# [1] -123  113  116 -117
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Notes: For `regmatches` you need matching info, e.g. from `regexpr`. The regex should actually look sth like `"\\d+BT"`.</sub>

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(exposure = c("123BT", "113BB", "116BB", "117BT"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(readr) 
(-1)^grepl('BT', df$exposure)  * parse_number(df$exposure)
[1] -123  113  116 -117
```